# OBJLoader.js:459 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemError' of undefined in THREE.js using MTLLoader and OBJLoader to load a model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to use MTLLoader and OBJLoader to load the model. However, my code following does not work and displays

> OBJLoader.js:459 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemError'
> of undefined.

My code is as following:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/PointerLockControls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/MTLLoader.js"></script>

  <script>
    //const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000 );

    //fp view control variables
    var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

    var controlsEnabled = true;

    var moveForward = false;
    var moveBackward = false;
    var moveLeft = false;
    var moveRight = false;

    var prevTime = performance.now();
    var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
    var color = new THREE.Color();

    function init() { 
    
      var ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, ratio, 0.1, 100000);
      var Pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, -40, 0);
      camera.position.set(Pos.x, Pos.y, Pos.z);
      var Dir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
      camera.lookAt(Dir.x, Dir.y, Dir.z);

      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);
      controls.enabled = true;
      scene.add(controls.getObject());

      var onKeyDown = function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 38: //up
          case 87: //w
            moveForward = true;
            break;

          case 37: //left
          case 65: //a
            moveLeft = true;
            break;

          case 40: //down
          case 83: //s
            moveBackward = true;
            break;

          case 39: //right
          case 68: //d
            moveRight = true;
            break;
        }
      };

      var onKeyUp = function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 38: //up
          case 87: //w
            moveForward = false;
            break;

          case 37: //left
          case 65: //a
            moveLeft = false;
            break;

          case 40: //down
          case 83: //s
            moveBackward = false;
            break;

          case 39: //right
          case 68: //d
            moveRight = false;
            break;
        }
      };

      document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
      document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, false);

      loadSkyBox();
      loadHouse();

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
      });
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
      
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }
    
    init();
    animate();

    function animate() {
    
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      if (controlsEnabled == true) {
        var time = performance.now();
        var delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;

        velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
        velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

        direction.z = Number(moveForward) - Number(moveBackward);
        direction.x = Number(moveLeft) - Number(moveRight);
        direction.normalize();

        if (moveForward || moveBackward) velocity.z -= direction.z * 400.0 * delta;
        if (moveLeft || moveRight) velocity.x -= direction.x * 400.0 * delta;

        controls.getObject().translateX(velocity.x * delta);
        controls.getObject().translateZ(velocity.z * delta);

        prevTime = time;
      }

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      
    }

    function loadSkyBox() {
    
      const geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000, 100, 10000);
      const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
      const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

      const tex1 = loader.load('img/sky2.jpg');
      const tex2 = loader.load('img/sky2_new.jpg');
      var texture = loader.load('img/grass-texture4.jpg');
      const tex3 = loader.load('img/sky1.jpg');

      texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.repeat.set(128, 128);

      manager.onLoad = function() {

        const cubeMaterials = [
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: tex1,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
          }), //left
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: tex1,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
          }), //right
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: tex3,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
          }), //up
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
          }), //down
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: tex2,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
          }), //front 
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: tex2,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
          }) //back
        ];

        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, cubeMaterials);
        scene.add(cube);
      };
      
    }

    function loadHouse() {

      var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
      mtlLoader.load("model/house/house_10.mtl", function(materials) {
        materials.preload();

        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.load(
          //resource url
          "model/house/house_10.obj",
          //called when resource is loaded
          function(object) {
            object.position.y = -49;
            scene.add(object);
          },
          //called when loading is in progresses  
          function(xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
          },
          //called when loading has errors
          function(error) {
            console.log('An error happened' + error);
          }
        );
      });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In this code, I tried to import a house using objloader and mtlloader. The first one loads the frame and the second one loads the texture on it.

So why does this happen? Where is the problem? What is the solution?

Comment: Can you please ensure that all used files (`OBJLoader.js`, `MTLLoader.js`, `PointerLockControls.js` and `three.js`) are from the same release?

Comment: No, I cannot...